# How to Load Google Maps API site in a Android Application using JavaScript

Tags: android

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/android_v3.html

I tried for this tutorial for using javascript in android for google map,but I dont find any way to use the java script where to put the code of the javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for phonegap framework and use html and javascript

Answer (score 0):

put the javascript in the asset folder and use the webview.loadurl(file:///android_asset/filename) to load your html file

Comment: I tried to display simple html file page is displeyed,but when I tried to use html to display google map using javascript map is not displayed.

Comment: Just see the link which I have provided n please tell me how to use the javascript give in this tutorial..

Comment: I m trying to develop google map application which allow me to put markers on google map in android. If u know anything about it how do it then plese help me...